# Filebeat - No such input type exist: 'azure-eventhub'

Tags: azure, filebeat

I'm using the oss version 7.12 of filebeat and following the guide here to try and monitor my azure event hub. Everytime I try to run filebeat it gives me this error:

```
Exiting: Failed to start crawler: starting input failed: Error while initializing input: Error creating input. No such input type exist: 'azure-eventhub'
```

My config is pretty basic.

```
logging.level: info
logging.to_files: false
setup.dashboards.enabled: false
setup.template.enabled: false
setup.ilm.enabled: false



filebeat.inputs:
- type: azure-eventhub
  eventhub: "insights-logs-appservicehttplogs"
  consumer_group: "$Default"
  connection_string: "Endpoint=sb://somesapace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=blahblahblah"
  storage_account: "blobstorage"
  storage_account_key: "<omitted>"
  

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://elastic:9200"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is because I'm using the oss version of Filebeat. This module is only available for the non-oss version of Filebeat.